# Output $_GET from array

Tags: php, arrays, output

Hello I had a link...

'process.php?wpn=somevaluehere'

Where I want whatever value place on 'wpn' must get another value from array of values example.

```
   array (

        "somevaluehere" => 5,
        "somevalue10" => 10,
        "somevalue20" => 20

   );
```

then how I can output the array values, been trying to search over google but I failed to find it since I am very new PHP programmer but I learn pretty fast and somehow can understand them. And if it can't be found on the array list, I wish it do nothing.

Comment: Why are you asking this ? You should read a PHP book first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$values = array(
   "somevaluehere" => 5,
   "somevalue10" => 10,
   "somevalue20" => 20
);
echo $values[$_GET['wpn']];
```

Comment: Can you help me again by adding this one inside a function

'function myvalues() {
$down = myarrays(); //since I created the arrays as function
$content .= 'hello';
$content .= 'additional';
$content .= $down;

return $content }'

The array values was created as function and I can see that it echoed the the value of the selected array. However it does not echo on the middle, but instead it echo before the content. 

Sorry if I don't explain it well.

Comment: Thanks again, I solve it I just change the other function from echo to return.

Thanks